# Azure Webjob trigger on insert or update record in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webjobs

I want to get trigger on insertion or updation of any record in Azure table storage.  For that I have created a azure webjob with below method...

```
public static async Task ReadTableEntity(
       [QueueTrigger("inputqueue")] Contact contactInQueue,
       [Table("Contact", "ContactId", "CityId")] Contact contactInTable, TextWriter logger)
        {

            logger.WriteLine("triggered");

        }
```

But above method is not called after any record in table updated or new record inserted.

I want to get above method called on insert or update any record in table.

Please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-tables-how-to) on how to do this?

Comment: yes, I already read it. Can you correct me where I am wrong?

Comment: Did either of the 2 answers solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

This trigger isn't working like you are expecting it to. For that to be the case, it would need to be some type of "Table Trigger," which does not exist.

From the docs :

> Some of the code snippets show the Table attribute used in functions that are called **manually**, that is, not by using one of the trigger attributes.

In laymen terms: 
There is nothing listening for you making any changes to your Storage Tables. You need to trigger this call after you Insert or Update your Table Storage records.

In your Web Job, you could add something like this (from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to#manual)) to trigger your method :

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JobHost host = new JobHost();
            host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("CreateQueueMessage"), new { value = "Hello world!" });
        }

        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static void CreateQueueMessage(
            TextWriter logger,
            string value,
            [Queue("outputqueue")] out string message)
        {
            message = value;
            logger.WriteLine("Creating queue message: ", message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I known, there is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222974/azure-webjobs-table-trigger) about Azure WebJobs Table Trigger. Also, someone has posted a feature request issue [Add Trigger for Azure Table Storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/3). I would report this feature request, you could try to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Binding-Extensions-Overview) to build your own binding extensions or follow Mark C.'s solution to manually trigger the insert/update record in Azure Table Storage for a workaround.